# Declare global namespace with enum in vue typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to separate constant variable in `global.d.ts` or `global.ts`

in my `global.d.ts`

```
declare namespace Upload {
  export enum Status {
    SUCCESS = 'success',
    ERROR = 'error',
    ONGOING = 'uploading'
  }
}
```

or alternatively in `global.ts`

```
namespace Upload {
  export enum Status {
    SUCCESS = 'success',
    ERROR = 'error',
    ONGOING = 'uploading'
  }
}
```

Then using it in `FileUpload.vue`

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

// using it directly without aliasing also not work
import UPLOAD = Upload.Status 

@Component
export default class FileUpload extends Vue {    
  onUploaded(files: object[]) {
    const upload = files[0]
    let status: string
    if (upload.success) status = UPLOAD.SUCCESS
    else if (upload.error) status = UPLOAD.ERROR
    else status = UPLOAD.ONGOING
    this.progress(upload.response, status, Number(upload.progress))
  }
}
```

At compile/**transpile time**  there is no error. However, at **runtime** it gave me error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Upload is not defined
    at eval (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"/home/wildan/Projects/Sensorfied/EDI/edi-ui/node_modules/.cache/cache-loader"}!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?{"transpileOnly":true,"appendTsSuffixTo":[{}],"happyPackMode":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/FileUpload.vue (app.js:836), <anonymous>:37:14)
    at Object../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"/home/wildan/Projects/Sensorfied/EDI/edi-ui/node_modules/.cache/cache-loader"}!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?{"transpileOnly":true,"appendTsSuffixTo":[{}],"happyPackMode":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/FileUpload.vue (app.js:836)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (FileUpload.vue?8134:1)
    at Object../src/components/FileUpload.vue (app.js:2281)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"/home/wildan/Projects/Sensorfied/EDI/edi-ui/node_modules/.cache/cache-loader"}!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?{"transpileOnly":true,"appendTsSuffixTo":[{}],"happyPackMode":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/CreateEthingDialog.vue (app.js:828), <anonymous>:13:74)
    at Object../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"/home/wildan/Projects/Sensorfied/EDI/edi-ui/node_modules/.cache/cache-loader"}!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?{"transpileOnly":true,"appendTsSuffixTo":[{}],"happyPackMode":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/CreateEthingDialog.vue (app.js:828)
```

Also try declaring without namespace and still doesn't work.

```
declare const enum Status
// declare enum Status
{
  SUCCESS = 'success',
  ERROR = 'error',
  ONGOING = 'uploading',
  SKIP = 'skip'
}
```

But if I declare it like this in `FileUpload.vue`, it will work

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-namespace
namespace Upload {
  export enum Status {
    SUCCESS = 'success',
    ERROR = 'error',
    ONGOING = 'uploading'
  }
}
import UPLOAD = Upload.Status
```

I also try to use `export const enum` but it also not working.

Comment: Indeed you cannot export enum with "const" keyword, but you're right, you have to export the enum.

Maybe you miss the "import { Status } from 'global.ts'" in your FileUpload.vue.
I use enum in my project but without namespace.

Did you fix your issue?

Comment: In the end I export enum as a module rather than declaring it in the declaration file. However, that is not the desireable pattern in my project structure as it made extra Line of Code in the local module.

Comment: Is there any solution to do this using typescript, I'm too trying to use enums globally inside plugin, how to do this?